# How to remove border of pop up menu in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, cmenu

I have custom class which is is inherited from `CMenu` class. I am trying to change the background color of the menu items. But the border of the menu items remain unchanged. Following are my overridden functions:

```
void CNewMenu::MeasureItem(LPMEASUREITEMSTRUCT lpMeasureItemStruct)
{
    lpMeasureItemStruct->itemHeight = 100;
    lpMeasureItemStruct->itemWidth = 150;
}

void CNewMenu::DrawItem(LPDRAWITEMSTRUCT lpDrawItemStruct)
{
    CRect rectFull(lpDrawItemStruct->rcItem); 
    COLORREF TextRect = COLORREF(RGB(0, 0, 0)); 
    CDC* pDC = CDC::FromHandle(lpDrawItemStruct->hDC);
    pDC->FillSolidRect(&rectFull, TextRect);
    pDC->TextOut(rectFull.left, rectFull.top, ((MenuObject*)lpDrawItemStruct->itemData)->m_strCaption);
}
```

How do I remove the border or change the color of the border?

I am referring to grey border around pop up menu

[image]

Comment: What border are you referring to? The code snippet is not a code you are using, or your menu background would be black. Please post the actual code.

Comment: I have edited my question with a supporting picture

Comment: Sorry, I was quite busy by the end of 2021., did not abandon you. I think I understand what you are trying to do.  to the best of my knowledge, you won't be able to do it using owner drawn menu or in the class derived from CMenu.
Unless somebody else finds what I am missing, this would require a higher level of interaction. The only way I see how you can achieve it is by hooking Window creation and using it to subclass the menu window. this would allow for controlling the drawing of the NC area.